# Ошибка в jupyter Using `tqdm.autonotebook.tqdm` in notebook mode. Use `tqdm.tqdm` instead to force console mode (e.g. in jupyter console)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема. python - 3.11.4[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Написано же всё, используйте `tqdm.tqdm`

Comment: А как? Я не понимаю

Comment: Я решил!!! Спасибо всем кто помог

Comment: Как решил? И кто ругался то на самом деле - библиотека `shap`?

Comment: Я модуль tqdm импортировал